# Compare two Maps & Identify modified value of a existing key

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm working on a problem, where for the first time i want to upload **Excel file**, read it & store into a MySQL DB. I'm done with this part & everything is working as expected.

Form the 2nd time whenever i'll upload **Excel file** again(Excel file can have exactly same data as DB or modified already existing data or both modified already existing data & newly added data), I've to compare it with the data available in MySQL & identify the changes.
I'm reading Excel file using **Apache POI** library & storing it in a `Map<Integer, List<MyCell>` where key is a *Row Number* & its value is `List<MyCell>` which is basically *List of columns*. 
I'm able to identify the newly added records (newly added keys & their values in 
a `Map`) by this logic

```
Map<Integer, List<MyCell>> filteredMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Integer key : datafromExcel.keySet()) {
    if (datafromDB.containsKey(key)) {
        datafromDB.remove(key);
    } else {
            filteredMap.put(key, datafromExcel.get(key));
    }
}
```

But I didn't succeed in finding existing modified record(existing modified value of a same key in a **Map**)

How can i get this?

Comment: So you know you have same row, but do not know what columns to update? Also what is definition of `datafromDB`

Comment: Please provide the definitions of the two maps you want to compare.

Comment: @Piro No..I have to identify the change of a existing row means change in any column data of a existing row. Definition of both the maps is same i.e Map<Integer, List<MyCell>>

Answer (score 0):

To check the modified values you have to compare the list coming from DB and excel with respective key.
Like I'm showing you just comparison of list here :

```
      Collection<String> similar = new HashSet<String>( fromDB.get(key) );
      Collection<String> different = new HashSet<String>();
      different.addAll( fromDB.get(key) );
      different.addAll( fromExcel.get(key) );

      similar.retainAll( fromExcel.get(key) );
      different.removeAll( similar );
      if(different.size()>0){
         SOP("NO CHANGE");
      }
```

Modify as per your logic if MyCell(I have used String here) is a class, you can use comparator.

**Hope this will help**

.

Answer (score 0):

For key existing in your database you are calling `datafromDB.remove(key);`.

So immediatelly you find the modified record you remove it and do not longer know you had such record. Clearly you have to do something more than `datafromDB.remove(key);` or do not remove data for key at all.